# Sudo -i giving error

Tags: linux, sudo

I have created a user1 and trying to switch user to user2 account using `sudo -i user2`. However I am getting this error:

```
Sorry, user user1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash -c user2' as root on hostname.
```

Please assist me on this.

Comment: Did you mean to write `sudo -iu user2`?

Comment: I am still getting error.
user1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash -c user2' as root on host.

Is there any rules to add on /etc/sudoers file to get the result i wanted

Comment: Please add the contents of `/etc/sudoers` to your question if you'd like us to answer that. What did you add to it already to give `user1` sudo permissions in the first place?

Answer (score 6):

`sudo -i user2` does not switch to `user2` at all. It literally means "run command `user2` as root, in an environment that matches root's login environment."

To switch to `user2`, the command needs to include the `-u user2` option.

If `sudo -iu user2` does not work, then maybe you have some sort of script, alias or shell function that modifies the command further? Please run `type -a sudo` or `command -v sudo` to find out what actually gets executed when you run the command.

Alternatively, if you have a very, very old system, it might not understand all the options the same way the modern `sudo` does. But that would mean the system would be more than 20 years old...

Try running `sudo -l`: it should list all the current `/etc/sudoers` entries that are applicable to you.

The `/etc/sudoers` entry to allow `user1` to run a shell as `user2` would be:

```
user1 ALL=(user2) /bin/bash
```

or to allow running any commands as `user2`:

```
user1 ALL=(user2) ALL
```

(The first `ALL` represents the hostname. Unless you are in a large environment that uses a shared `sudoers` file, it is typically unused and `ALL` is used as a placeholder, to avoid difficulties with `sudo` if there is a problem in hostname resolution.)

Answer (score 0):

The sudo [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)
explains that you'll want to use the `-u` option
to switch to that other user.

See also the documentation on how to
[configure](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) sudo permissions.